# How can I access remote host on VM via snmp protocol?

Tags: snmp

I have two VMs installed and I want to request a `snmpwalk system` from one VM to another. I have two different IPs for each VM but when I write my request `snmpwalk 192.168.1.32 -v 2c -c public system`I receive a `No Response from 192.168.1.32`

I have my `snmpd` installed on 192.168.1.32.

Ping works perfectly between the two hosts.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you ping from one to the other? Ssh from one to the other?

Comment: yes, ping works perfectly

Comment: Is snmp on the target configured to respond with version 2c to the "public" authenticator?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. Can you please guide me how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Start by looking at the snmpd.conf on your server

Comment: Thanks, I believe it has to be in ACCESS CONTROL section, right? For now I have  #  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
#rocommunity public  localhost
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                                 #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
 rocommunity6 public  default   -V systemonly

Answer (score 1):

First open snmpd.conf file with text editor (for ex. nano)

```
nano /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

At the very beginning uncomment **agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161** and comment **agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161** allowing the "agent" machine to be checked by external hosts

```
#  Listen for connections from the local system only
#agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161
```

Restart snmpd service

```
service snmpd restart
```

Try as a basic command on your manager machine:

```
snmpwalk xxx.xxx.x.xx -v 2c -c public system
```

where *xxx.xxx.x.xx* - is **IP of agent (target machine)**,
*2c* - is a **snmp protocol version**,
*public* is a **community string**;